# When using FFI with Deno how to deal with struct returned by a C function?

Tags: typescript, ffi, deno

I have a `C` function that returns a struct CommandList, like below

```
typedef struct Command {
  enum CommandId id;
  const char *arg1;
  const char *arg2;
} Command;

typedef struct CommandList {
  const struct Command *test_commands;
  uintptr_t len;
} CommandList;
```

I have declared it like this

```
const dylib = Deno.dlopen(
  libName,
  {
    load_scenario: { parameters: ["buffer"], result: { struct: CommandList } },
    free_test: { parameters: [{ struct: CommandList }], result: "void" },
  } as const,
  );
```

the call

```
console.log(dylib.symbols.load_scenario(buf));
```

prints

```
Uint8Array(16) [
  112, 61, 21, 11, 167, 85,
    0,  0,  7,  0,   0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0
]
```

That looks correct as I know that there is 7 elements in the array, but how could I map this struct to something less raw than a Uint8array?

Is there any way to map this array to let's say:

```
interface Command {
    id: Uint32Array,
    arg1: Deno.UnsafePointerView<Uint8Array>;
    arg2: Deno.UnsafePointerView<Uint8Array>;
}

interface CommandList {
    data: Deno.UnsafePointerView<Command>;
    len: number;
}
```

In the end I would like to write code like this:

```
  const command_list: CommandList = dylib.symbols.load_scenario(buf);

  for (let i = 0; i < command_list.len; i++) {
    const command: Command = command_list.data[i];
    console.log(command.id, command.arg1, command.arg2);
  }
```

I've read the doc, dig through Deno ffi tests https://raw.githubusercontent.com/littledivy/deno/21e77c01b75e6f9fda320b4abf56433acb63bbc5/test_ffi/tests/test.js
and googled a lot with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Uint8Array is backed by an array buffer. You can access the raw buffer and then use it to construct a DataView. A DataView can be used to access different types of data in the buffer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, it seems DataView may help, but I don't see how to map data to pointer. Please see edited question for what I want to do the end.

Comment: Ok, finaly understood that DataView is the (sole?) way to go. As soon as my code is open sourced I'll link it here so it may help others.